# Change link within block

Tags: navigation

http://www.ascoworld.com/services

On the above page, there is a block with three icons that links to the wrong pages. I want to change where they link to but can't seem to find out how. Apologies, but I am as new as can be at this. I didn't create the website and have never used Drupal before, I just got passed it and told to fix these issues.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It's look like its created using views. try to check it here `/admin/structure/views` and look for views services

Answer (score 0):

The page layout is broken but I assume that you are talking about **Services** menu block. Based on the HTML source it is a menu block and a main menu to be specific. So to the change the link go to `Structure > Menus > Main Menu` and change the link path there.

**UPDATE:**

Since the page is broken in my end my above answer is wrong. As @iamroald comment it is created via Views. Go to `Structure > Views > Services`. It seems like there is a `Token` substitution in there.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**:

The views block content is created in node, node type `service group`. so if you wanted to change the link you can update the alias pattern here `/admin/config/search/path/patterns`.

[image]

or manually update it here `admin/config/search/path`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You seem to be right. However, when I go to edit, I can see the three links but no option to change them (screenshot added to question).

Comment: Click the content path and you can override its link

Comment: Updated image. I can't edit it by clicking the path. And when I go to configure > Edit Content: Path – there is no option to change it.

Comment: Sorry just ignore the last comment, it is made in content type and it shows the result base on the existing content

Comment: I mean the content

Comment: I don't know how this happened (as I didn't create the site), but there are two contents with the same name (different content types – they are fairly similar but not the same in terms of appearance). The sidemenu links to the correct one, and the icons at the bottom links to the wrong one (as shown). The link in the screenshot for the icons should be services/offshore, not just /offshore.

Comment: I see, it might be aliased, you can correct the alias on that content type. to out put the link to services/offshore

Comment: Can you try to check the path `offshore` if existing here `admin/config/search/path`

Comment: you can update it's alias to `services/offshore`

Comment: I update my answer,

Comment: That didn't work as the correct path already exists. I have found a cheat work around though. I just redirected the wrong content to the correct content. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The Link is coming from the content path field that means node link. If you need to add custom link. you need to create a field in service group content type. Then edit all the contents of type "service group" and add your link there. After that add that field in your view and delete content path field from view.